# Can a moderator change the correct answer to an old question?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, moderator-abilities, time

I've seen an answer of mine be considered "not the answer" (another answer was checked). About one day later, my answer was considered the one instead.

Now, 3 days later, my answer was changed again and the other got the mark.

- What is the time limit for the OP to change the correct answer?
- Can a moderator do that at any time?

Comment: Also releated: [If my question's accepted answer is no longer the best, should I change the accepted answer?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335658)

Comment: And also: [Lock accepted answer after few days of being accepted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278233)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moderators cannot change the accepted answer at any time, for any reason.

The only person who has control over the accepted answer status is the person who originally asked the question. They can set or change the accepted answer at any time, for any reason they choose. There is never a time limit.

The acceptance mark is intended to be a signal that the person who asked the question found *this answer* to be *the most helpful*. A moderator couldn't possibly determine that, unless they first give us mind-reading abilities.

(Nitpicker's Corner: if a moderator asked the question originally, then they would obviously be able to set/change the accepted answer, but not because they are a moderator.)

Comment: The "Nitpicker's Corner" makes your answer perfect.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Cody has his finger firmly on the pulse of the community here.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the time limit for the OP to change the correct answer?

There's no time limitation on changing the accepted answer.

> Can a moderator do that <strike>at any time</strike>?

No, and I hope they'll never have the ability to.